# Play Scala & Slick3, got "Column xx cannot be null" error at a column with "NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, slick-3.0

I'm creating a web app using Play Framework 2.6 with slick 3.2.1.
When I try to insert a record into the table "USER", which has created_at column with "NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" (I'm using MySQL), the database throws an error "Column 'created_at' cannot be null".

I know that the SQL generated by slick is wrong. The statement is trying to insert null into the created_at column. What is the proper way to let slick generate SQL that doesn't contain created_at column?

**Excerpt of the scala code.**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime

case class User(
    id: Option[Long],
    accountId: Long,
    name: String,
    description: Option[String] = None,
    createdAt: Option[DateTime: = None,
)

class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def accountId = column[Long]("account_id")
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def description = column[Option[String]]("description")
  def createdAt = column[Option[DateTime]]("created_at")
  def * = (id.?, accountId, name, description, createdAt) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}

object Users extends TableQuery(new UserTable(_)) {
}

val user = User(None, accountId, name, description)
val insert = for {
  newId <- (Users returning Users.map(_.id)) += user
} yield newId

db.run(insert)
```

**generated SQL**

```
[debug] s.j.J.statement - Preparing insert statement (returning: id): insert into `user` (`account_id`,`name`,`description`,`created_at`)  values (?,?,?,?)

[debug] s.j.J.parameter - /------+--------+---------+-----------\
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - | 1    | 2      | 3       | 4         |
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - | Long | String | VARCHAR | TIMESTAMP |
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - |------+--------+---------+-----------|
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - | 1    | user01 | NULL    | NULL      |
[debug] s.j.J.parameter - \------+--------+---------+-----------/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found two ways to work (hack) around this issue (using Slick 3.2.3). Fortunately, for my use case, I am not using Slick to create the tables or generate the table classes, so I don't really care if the schema it would generate is valid.

Assume we have a simple user model/table:

```
case class User(id: Long, name: String, createdAt: Timestamp, updatedAt: Timestamp)

class UsersDAO(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "users") {
  def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("name")
  def createdAt = column[Timestamp]("created_at", O.AutoInc)
  def updatedAt = column[Timestamp]("updated_at", O.AutoInc)

  override def * = (id, name, createdAt, updatedAt) <>
    (User.tupled, User.unapply)
}
```

**Option 1: Use a custom insert method**

```
object UsersDAO extends TableQuery(new UsersDAO(_)) {
  def create(u: User) = this map { c =>
    (c.name) // only include columns you want to send
  } returning this.map(_.id) += (u.name)
}
```

**Option 2: Mark the fields as `O.AutoInc`**

If you mark the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` columns with `O.AutoInc` (as I did above), you can simply use the `+=` syntax:

```
object UsersDAO extends TableQuery(new UsersDAO(_)) {
  def create(u: User) = this returning this.map(_.id) += user
}
```

There seems to be several issues currently open related to this. Hopefully once they're resolved, there will be a better way.
https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1448
https://github.com/slick/slick/pull/1533

Answer (score 1):

Rethink your example. Your table does not accept `null` as value of column `created_at`. But your domain model allows that this field can be `None` which cannot be represented in database in any other way than `null`. So you if you want slick to generate correct query you have to change type of `created_at` to `DateTime`.

Comment: In that way, do you mean that I have to write `User(None, accountId, name, description, new DateTime())` for creating a User instance to insert, and the modifier `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on the table is never used with slick?

Comment: In your case, yes it is not used. Whether it is possible to implement it the way you want i don't know right now. Consider reading this:
http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#inserting
It should be possible to achieve default value in table definition, but i am not sure

Answer (score 0):

`createdAt` cannot be an `Option`, you may put there `DateTime.now` to avoid usage of `Option`. Also `DateTime` column mapper is required:

```
import slick.lifted.MappedTypeMapper
import java.sql.Date
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import slick.lifted.TypeMapper.DateTypeMapper

object DateTimeMapper {
  implicit def date2dt = MappedTypeMapper.base[DateTime, Date] (
    dt => new Date(dt.getMillis),
    date => new DateTime(date)
  )
}
```

Or you will most probably need it for `Timestamp`, not `Date`:

```
 implicit def dateTime  =
      MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
        dt => new Timestamp(dt.getMillis),
        ts => new DateTime(ts.getTime)
  )
```

And if you do not want to deal with `DateTime.now`, you may do something like this:

```
def created = column[DateTime]("createdAt", SqlType("timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"))
```

Additional info here:
http://queirozf.com/entries/scala-slick-dealing-with-datetime-timestamp-attributes

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your projection you have to lift `created_at`, just like you lift your id.

So your projection would become:

`def * = (id.?, accountId, name, description, createdAt.?) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)`

Notice the `.?` after createdAt.